# Does this method of appdata work with linux also?

Tags: c#, java, operating-system

I would just like to know... Does this code work in linux and mac as well as windows?

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

The reason I ask is because I know that windows manages appdata differently than Mac and linux.

Comment: That code does not appear to use anything from the integrated Java API; what is that code?

Comment: This is what I found to get appdata directory on a quick search. What code would you use?

Comment: Well, that's not even Java, so I'd use the correct(?) language first.  As for the C# code you've shown, I don't know whether it works cross-OS.  In Java, I've always simply used the unix home to store application data.

Comment: Ok, I thought that was java code. How would you find appdata in java?

Comment: Refer to the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12520128/1247781) I posted for finding appdata in Java.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see that answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, there is a difference in how to acquire the application data directory between Windows and unix operating systems.  As for C#, the language your example code is in (despite the question being tagged "java"), I can't say for sure.

In the past, I've always used the AppData folder on Windows and simply the unix home for unix systems.

```
public static String getAppDataPath() {
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
        return System.getenv("APPDATA");
    } else {
        return getUnixHome();
    }
}

public static String getUnixHome() {
    String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    return home != null ? home : "~";
}
```

Also note that on unix systems, it is preferable to make appdata in the user home hidden, so you should begin your files with `.` on mac and linux.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and I thought that code was java.

Comment: No worries, we all make mistakes.  Don't forget to mark answers as accepted if you select them as your final answer.

Comment: Done! Thanks for teaching me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of 'appdata' is a Windows-specific concept. While Linux and OSX systems have some conventions for storing data, no one calls them 'appdata'. On Linux or OSX, it's not uncommon to write files with names beginning with '.' into the home directory. On OSX, there is also an elaborate Apple-specific system preferences.

You might simply consider using the Java Preferences API and not deal with 'appdata' at all, except to the extend that the Windows implementation of the JVM decide what to do with it.